# Mongodb 3.2.6 pauses a lot when heavy writes

Tags: mongodb, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

I have one collection with 0.3 billion of document(212GB data) with no index ( _id index is 11GB ) . 32GB RAM , 8 CPU Amazon Linux AMI m4.2xlarge 500GB SSD EBS volume. 3-4Mb writes per second , Mongodb 3.2.6 with wiredTiger storage engine  , block_compressor is snappy . I have optimized  according to the instructions from Mongodb documentation of installation on Amazon EC2 .

What I found is , server inconsistently use lots of CPU to 700% or 30% of total CPU . All writes and reads was paused for around 5-20s . I read lots of material online and guess it might be the reasons of wiredTiger snapshot checkpoints process or data compression process.

The 5-20s pause is really annoying and other applications will be also impacted .

My question is what are the alternatives to resolve this issue ? Will it become even worst when my data is growing up to 1 billion documents (no index needed at this moment , just heavy writes )?

Possible  solutions I can come up with

1. Shading (my most jobs are heavy writes , no reads , no query , no index needed at this moment )
2. revert back to MMAPv1
3. more tuning or optimization
4. using another database

---

How did I resolve this issue ?

I changed amazon ebs volume from ext4 to xfs format by following this  [How to create and mount an XFS file system on Linux](http://ask.xmodulo.com/create-mount-xfs-file-system-linux.html) and [Making an Amazon EBS Volume Available for Use](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/ebs-using-volumes.html).

Now the system looks like this . No pause at all . 
[image: screenshot from mongostat]
[image: screenshot from iotop]

Comment: Are you using gp2 or io1 EBS?  Either way, you need to collect better statistics of where the bottleneck is.  If the CPU time is mainly I/O wait, you will likely need to improve IO perf, and there are a number of ways to do that.  Do you have any metrics collection on the instance, other than CloudWatch (which won't give the metrics needed here)?

Comment: You said that you implemented MongoDB production recommendations so I am assuming you already use XFS. Did you check if you are saturating I/O?

Comment: @Kiril I am using ext4 now . I am starting a new test to collect I/O statistics . Will keep you posted .  I am using gp2 EBS .

Comment: @RichardMao definitely try with xfs as these pauses sound awful lot like ext4 issue or at least mount ext4 partition with noatime option.

Comment: @Kiril I am using mount ext4 ebs volume now . So , I will test XFS mount with noatime option then . I will keep you posted . Thanks .

Comment: @RichardMao noatime is only needed for ext4

Comment: @Kiril thanks a lot , I will use defaults,nofail        0       2 , from amazon ebs volume attach instructions . [link](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/ebs-using-volumes.html)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This sounds an awful lot like an ext4 problem. When running WiredTiger you should use XFS.

- [MongoDB Production Notes](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/administration/production-notes/#kernel-and-file-systems)  on the file system topic
- For technical details, see [SERVER-18314](https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/SERVER-18314)